# Converting time to specific format and conversely, Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

What is the easiest way to convert time to specific time format?
For example, how to convert `340` minutes to `hh:mm` format?
And how to get back the minutes from `hh:mm`?
Is it possible to do that with moment.js?

```
320 minutes -> 05:20
05:20 -> 320 minutes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
function getTimeFromMins(mins) {
    // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035598/how-to-convert-minutes-to-hours-using-moment-js
    if (mins >= 24 * 60 || mins < 0) {
        throw new RangeError("Valid input should be greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1440.");
    }
    var h = mins / 60 | 0,
        m = mins % 60 | 0;
    return moment.utc().hours(h).minutes(m).format("HH:mm");
}

function getMinutesFromTime(time) {
    var t = moment.utc(time, "HH:mm")
    return parseInt(t.format("HH")*60) +  parseInt(t.format("mm"))
}

console.log(getTimeFromMins(320)); 
console.log(getMinutesFromTime("05:20"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: seriously there is no other, easier way?

Comment: What more you need? Momentjs doesn't provide function and there is nothing called `magic` !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about momentjs but since you asked this with the angular tag I can offer a possible solution using pipes.

If you have a Date object you can simply use Angular's date pipe which is super easy to use. When displaying a date in a template you can use like this:

```
<div>{{ someDate | date 'hh:mm' }}</div>
```

The documentation for the [date pipe is here.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html). I highly recommend looking at it.

If what you're looking for is to convert a string representation of a time like '05:30', then I would suggest writing your own pipe. Here is an example of some pipes that convert time to minutes and vice versa.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'timeToMinutes'})
export class TimeConversionPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor() {}

  transform(time: string): string {
    let split = time.split(':');
    let hours = split[0];
    let minutes = split[1];
    return (parseInt(hours) * 60 + parseInt(minutes)).toString();
  }
}


@Pipe({name: 'minutesToTime'})
export class TimeConversionPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor() {}

  transform(minutes: string): string {
    let min = parseInt(minutes);
    let hours = Math.floor(min / 60);
    let remainingMinutes = min % 60;
    return hours + ":" + remainingMinutes;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I didn't know about split, it will be certainly helpful but still I am looking for an easier way if there is any.

Comment: Are you dealing with a Date object or just a string?

Comment: Just an ordinary string.

Comment: If all you're doing is manipulating strings like "05:30" then I don't think you need moment.js. Rather, its important for you to get used to writing pipes and directives because they are so common in Angular.