# converting minutes to hours react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

can someone help me out to write a function in react native to convert 234mins to 3hrs:54mins, and when it is less than 1hr, it shows just 59mins instead of 0hrs:59mins. Kindly indicate if I should give an example code.

Comment: Have you looked into packages/libraries like moment.js or day.js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript seconds to time string with format hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035598/how-to-convert-minutes-to-hours-using-moment-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
const convertMinsToTime = (mins) => {
  let hours = Math.floor(mins / 60);
  let minutes = mins % 60;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
  return `${hours}hrs:${minutes}mins`;
}
```

Comment: many thanks, exactly what I needed, gracias. but I do not want the 0h:20mins if its less than 60, I just want 20mins

Comment: change return to: `\`${hours ? \`${hours}hrs:\` : ''}${minutes}mins\``;